# Can't get data using req.body

Tags: node.js

what's wrong in my code I can't getting data using req.body

```
router.post("/",(req,res)=>{
try{
    const book = {
        id:nanoid(idLength),
        ...req.body
    }
```

Comment: I guess u need a body parser added to the express object. Do you have them configured with your express app?